# Python3, не получается сделать запись в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python3.
Для записи в файл, делаю массив массивом строк. Но почему то при записи в файл, к нулевому элементу добавляется "0"
Что это такое?

```
file = open('sentences.txt', 'r')

lines = list(file)

data = []
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    data.append(line)
file.close()

import re

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = re.split('[^a-z]', data[i])
    for j in range(data[i].count('')):
        data[i].remove('')

dictionary = {}
count = 0
for words in data:
    for word in words:
        if not (word in dictionary.keys()):
            dictionary[word] = count
            count += 1

import numpy as np

matrix = np.zeros((len(data), len(dictionary)))
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(dictionary)):
        Item = ()
        for item in dictionary.items():
            if item[1] == j:
                Item = item
                break
        matrix[i][j] = data[i].count(Item[0])

from scipy import spatial as sp

min1 = (0, 1) 
min2 = (0, 1)

shape = matrix.shape
for i in range(1, shape[0]):
    cosin = sp.distance.cosine(matrix[0], matrix[i])
    if (cosin < min1[1]):
        min2 = min1
        min1 = [i, cosin]
    elif (cosin < min2[1]):
        min2 = [i, cosin]
print('Номер первой найденной строки и её косинусное расстояние:', min1)
print('Номер второй найденной строки и её косинусное расстояние:', min2)
#Номер первой найденной строки и её косинусное расстояние: [6, 0.7327387580875756]
#Номер второй найденной строки и её косинусное расстояние: [4, 0.7770887149698589]

print(min1[0])
#6

file_obj = open('out.txt', 'w')
file_obj.writelines(min1[0] + " " for min1 in map(str, min1))
file_obj.writelines(min2[0] + " " for min2 in map(str, min2))
file_obj.close()

file_obj = open('out.txt', 'r')
print(file_obj.read())
#6 0 4 0
```

Comment: хм, всё равно не понимаю, как тогда сделать запись в файл только 6 и 4 (которые берутся из min1 и min2)?

Comment: код не ваш чтоли ? нужно min1[0] так и записывайте min1[0] .без всего лишнего